# Trace what functions are fired from an event

Tags: javascript, trace

I want to trace a button click event to know which functions are fired when the user clicks on a button send some data.

ex:

```
<input type="button" id="btnPost" onclick="fire(... , ...)" />
```

or

```
$("#btnPost").click(function() {
 // blah blah
});
```

In the above case I want to view the method fire or the jQuery code. Manual inspection is not possible due to the sheer size of the JavaScript.

What tools can assist with tracing JavaScript events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this in Chrome, but should be possible in FF two.

- Load the page fully.
- Open developer tools
- Change to sources tab.
- Click the pause button (Nothing will happen just yet. Make sure
  break points are enabled, icon of the far right)
- Then click the button.
- Chrome should break into the very next javascript line executed by it.

  [image: Screenshot]

EDIT: How to the same on Firefox with [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/)

[image: How to do the same on Firefox with Firebug]

Comment: A screenshot will be appreciated !

Comment: Fun fact of the day: jsfiddle has implanted this same developer tool from Apple. You can use it on every browser supported. [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yegYu.png)

Comment: Sorry cant get it :/
I've the latest FF but the view are completely different !

Comment: @Sourav Check if the new screenshot of Firefox would help, I'm using Firebug on it, you should also do the same if you don't yet

Comment: I've FF 17.0.1 and Firebug 1.11.1 but still the screen is different :( plz help